Problema de lectura de datos de Firestore
En este código de kotlin que lee datos de firestore, cuando lo ejecuto en mi emulador android, el textview con nombre tv1 no imprime el dato leido"nombre", creo que el problema esta en la lectura de datos de firestore por las depuraciones que he hecho pero no esta claro, tambien puede ser un problema de actualizacion del textView pero tambien pueden haber otros fallos. Me he asegurado de que el emulador tenga conexion a wifi y de que los nombres de la base de datos y los del codigo coincidan. El codigo correspondiente es este:
package com.example.elpecador

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore

class Users : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    private var usera_nombre: Any? = null
    private var usera_rating: Int? = null
    private var usera_numero_ratings: Int? = null
    private var usera_imagen: Any? = null
    private var userb_nombre: Any? = null
    private var userb_rating: Int? = null
    private var userb_numero_ratings: Int? = null
    private var userb_imagen: Any? = null
    private var userA: Map<String, Any?>? = null
    private var userB: Map<String, Any?>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_users)

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.scrollView)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }

        db.collection("users").document("user_a").get().addOnSuccessListener {
            
            usera_nombre = it.get("nombre") as String?
            usera_rating = it.get("rating") as Int?
            usera_numero_ratings = it.get("numero_ratings") as Int?
            usera_imagen = it.get("imagen") as String?
            userA = mapOf(
                "nombre" to usera_nombre,
                "rating" to usera_rating,
                "numero_ratings" to usera_numero_ratings,
                "imagen" to usera_imagen,
            )
            db.collection("users").document("user_b").get().addOnSuccessListener {
                userb_nombre = it.get("nombre") as String?
                userb_rating = it.get("rating") as Int?
                userb_numero_ratings = it.get("numero_ratings") as Int?
                userb_imagen = it.get("imagen") as String?
                userB = mapOf(
                    "nombre" to userb_nombre,
                    "rating" to userb_rating,
                    "numero_ratings" to userb_numero_ratings,
                    "imagen" to userb_imagen,
                )
                val ratings = arrayOf(
                    userA?.get("rating") as? Int,
                    userB?.get("rating") as? Int
                ).filterNotNull().toTypedArray()

                ratings.sortDescending()

                val maxRating = ratings.firstOrNull() // Obtener el rating más grande

                // Actualizar el TextView con el nombre del user que tiene el rating más grande
                val userConMasRating = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv1)
                userConMasRating.text = when (maxRating) {
                    userb_rating -> userB?.get("nombre").toString()
                    usera_rating -> userA?.get("nombre").toString()
                    else -> ""
                }
            }


        }


    }
}

En este codigo, al ejecutarlo, el texview no se actualiza pero ha habido casos, con otras posiciones del codigo en las que en el textView se imprimia null

¿Qué depuraciones has hecho? Ve poniendo puntos de interrupción en el código y revisando el valor de los objetos en cada punto hasta dar con el problema. ¿Está trayendo datos? ¿Qué datos? ¿Coinciden con las comparaciones que hay en el código? Una depuración adecuada responderá a esas y otras eventuales preguntas que conducen a encontrar cuál es el problema. Si no sabes cómo depurar conviene que aprendas. Te vas a ahorrar pero que muuuuchas horas desarrollando tus programas.

Solucionado!!!!!!
El error estaba en que las variables numericas que se extraen de firestore vienen en tipo long por defecto y la conversion no se estaba realizando correctamente. He añadido el as? Long?.toInt() para que funcione. Esta es la parte del codigo que fallaba con las correcciones:
db.collection("users").document("user_a").get().addOnSuccessListener {
            usera_nombre = it.getString("nombre")
            usera_rating = (it.get("rating") as? Long)?.toInt()
            usera_numero_ratings = (it.get("numero_ratings") as? Long)?.toInt()
            usera_imagen = it.getString("imagen")
            userA = mapOf(
                "nombre" to usera_nombre,
                "rating" to usera_rating,
                "numero_ratings" to usera_numero_ratings,
                "imagen" to usera_imagen,
            )

